# Visualize and Visualise national recognition?

Tags: spelling

Which spelling is recognized more as the proper spelling globally?

Answer (score 1):

"Globally" doesn't make sense.  There are several dialects of English, with different spellings of some words.  Generally there are two groups of dialects: American and British spelling.

Visualize is the correct spelling in American English.  Visualise is correct in British English, but Visualize is a recognised variant spelling in British spelling. Commonwealth countries (Australia, India etc but not Canada) tend to follow British Spelling.

Pick a dialect and stick to it.